# Interface for two methods that take different parameters

Tags: c#, interface, console-application

Probably a noobish question to ask but I was hoping someone could help me here as I'm completely lost. I have a task to do for work (I'm a graduate programmer and they have set me a sort of "challenge") - don't worry, I'm not asking for an outright answer and it's not part of my day to day job, just sort of an extra. But I think it involves Interfaces and I am completely lost when it comes to them so was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Basically I was given a Registry walker that loops through the registry and prints out the keys and values on the console app based on a given parameter (see below for code)

```
    class RegistryList
{
    public void RegistryWalker(RegistryKey _key, int _indent)
    {
        Output.RegistryOutPut(_indent, String.Format("Key: {0}", _key.Name.Split('\\').Last()));
        string[] straValues = _key.GetValueNames();

        foreach (string strValue in straValues)
        {
            RegistryValueKind kind = _key.GetValueKind(strValue);
            Output.RegistryOutPut(_indent + 1, String.Format("Value: {0}", strValue));
        }

        string[] straSubKeys = _key.GetSubKeyNames();

        foreach (string strSubKey in straSubKeys)
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey subKey = _key.OpenSubKey(strSubKey);
                RegistryWalker(subKey, _indent + 2);

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Denied Access");
            }
        }
    }
```

I had to come up with a similar one for files, which I have completed (again see below)

```
    class FileList
{

     public void FileWalker()
    {
        StringCollection log = new StringCollection();

        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

        foreach (string dr in drives)
        {
            DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(dr);

            if (!di.IsReady)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} could not be read", di.Name);
                continue;
            }

            DirectoryInfo rootDir = di.RootDirectory;
            Output.FileOutput(rootDir);

            Console.WriteLine("Files with restricted access:");

            foreach (string s in log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
}
```

For the record, the Output.RegistryOutput and Output.FileOutput calls in the code snippets above call separate output functions (which work fine, they print out each registry key and file path, but I need one function for both - see below's comments).

The final part of the task was to put the recursion into a separate function, which will either take a FileWalker instance or a RegistryWalker instance. Someone in work pointed me towards Interfaces to solve the problem but I am completely lost. These two functions will take different parameters so I cannot see how a single interface will work since if a registry walker is to be used it requires a RegistryKey and int values, but the File walker has no parameters. I have created a single IWalker interface (again, below) but I don't see how this will work for both functions.

```
    interface IWalker
{
    void Walker();
}
```

Can anyone shed light on this for me? And even if this is the correct way to go, I've been lost on this for quite a while now and definitely need a few pointers if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest way i think something like this

```
interface IWalker
{
    void Walker(object a=null, object b=null);
}

class RegistryList: IWalker
{
    public void Walker(object a, object b){
        var _key = (RegistryKey)a;
        var _indent = Convert.ToInt32(b)
        RegistryWalker(_key, _indent)
    }

    private void RegistryWalker(RegistryKey _key, int _indent)
    { 
        ....
    }
}

class FileListIWalker
{
    public void Walker(object a=null, object b=null){
        FileWalker();
    }

    public void FileWalker(){...}
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Visitor pattern, hope it helps.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern